# Svg не хочет отображается после вставки jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть такая структура в HTML

```
<div class="btn upload-images">
    <div class="text" style="display: none;">Upload</div>
</div>
```

После в js jquery я формирую SVG

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const loaderBlock = $('<div>').css({
        'display': 'flex',
        'position': 'relative',
        'align-content': 'space-around',
        'justify-content': 'center',
    });

    const svgElement = $('<svg>').attr({
        height: '24',
        width: '24',
        viewBox: '0 0 100 100',
    }).css({
        'display': 'block',
        'transform': 'rotate(-90deg)',
    });

    const circleElement = $('<circle>').attr({
        'cx': '50',
        'cy': '50',
        'r': '44',
    }).css({
        'stroke-dasharray': '276.32',
        'stroke-dashoffset': '276.32',
        'animation': 'fill-animation 750ms cubic-bezier(1,1,1,1) infinite',
        'fill': 'none',
        'stroke-width': '12px',
        'stroke-linecap': 'round',
        'stroke': '#000',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': 0,
        'right': 0,
        'top': 0,
        'bottom': 0,
    });

    svgElement.append(circleElement);

    loaderBlock.append(svgElement);

    $('.upload-images').append(loaderBlock);
});
```

И svg вставляется но она не имеет размеров, и что я не пытался делать, ничего не помогает. Самое интересное если я в HTML вручную вставляю это-же SVG абсолютно одинаковые, то через вручную вставку все нормально, но через js нет

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn upload-images">
    <div class="text" style="display: none;">Upload</div>
    <div class="loader-block">
        <svg class="svg-container" height="24" width="24" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <circle class="loader-svg animate-svg" cx="50" cy="50" r="44"></circle>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        const loaderBlock = $('<div>').css({
            'display': 'flex',
            'position': 'relative',
            'align-content': 'space-around',
            'justify-content': 'center',
        });

        const svgElement = $('<svg>').attr({
            height: '24',
            width: '24',
            viewBox: '0 0 100 100',
        }).css({
            'display': 'block',
            'transform': 'rotate(-90deg)',
        });

        const circleElement = $('<circle>').attr({
            'cx': '50',
            'cy': '50',
            'r': '44',
        }).css({
            'stroke-dasharray': '276.32',
            'stroke-dashoffset': '276.32',
            'animation': 'fill-animation 750ms cubic-bezier(1,1,1,1) infinite',
            'fill': 'none',
            'stroke-width': '12px',
            'stroke-linecap': 'round',
            'stroke': '#000',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'left': 0,
            'right': 0,
            'top': 0,
            'bottom': 0,
        });

        svgElement.append(circleElement);

        loaderBlock.append(svgElement);

        $('.upload-images').append(loaderBlock);
    });
</script>
```

Что может быть не так?

Comment: По "понятиям" jquery "$" = HTML .)  Т.е. по сути вы создаёте объект, но он не совсем SVG. Подробнее, вместе с решением вашей задачи, найдёте здесь — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/ И, на посошок, на всякий случай, замечу, что у вашего кружка заливка  fill: none

Comment: Да в целом принцип понял, получилось заспавнить мой SVG. Спасибо, и да fill: none так и надо :) я же тут просто использовал обводку.